# React-router - Set the current route to be the last route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

This is a pretty simple question but how can I update my view to be the last element in my list of routes?

Right now, I'm passing in an array of routes to my router but it's default setting the current route to the homepage. Is there a way I can set it to be the last element of my array of routes?

```
breadcrumbRoutes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      exact: true,
      name: "Device Policies",
      main: () => <h2>Device Policies View</h2>
    },
    {
      path: '/controlPanel',
      exact: true,
      name: "Control Panel",
      main: () => <h2>Control Panel View</h2>
    },
    {
      path: '/settings',
      exact: true,
      name: "Settings",
      main: () => <h2>Settings View</h2>
    }
  ]
```

I'd like to set the current view to be the settings page because my breadcrumbs would look something like this `Device Policies/Control Panel/Settings`.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not really how react-router works. There is no "default" view. If a user navigates to the `/` path of your app, then they will see the "Device Policies" component. If they navigate to the `/settings` path, they will see the "Settings View" component. etc.

Another issue here is that your routes are not set up to have a breadcrumb like you describe. You do not have a `Device Policies/Control Panel/Settings` route. You have three *separate* routes: `/`, `/controlPanel`, and `/settings`. If you want a `/controlPanel/settings` route, then you need to nest your control panel route inside of the root `/` route, and nest the settings route inside of *that* route.

If you did have a `/controlPanel/settings` route, then the way you might make that the "default" route would be to render a [`<Redirect>`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Redirect) component under the `/` route that points to `/controlPanel/settings`. Then you could have a `/home` route or similar that is your actual homepage/dashboard. That way when a user tries to go to `/`, they will be send to the settings page, but you can provide links to the `/home` route that will not redirect them anywhere (otherwise it would be impossible to have a "home" page if `/` *always* redirected to settings!)

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful! :-)

Comment: Another question: Say that I'm given a route `/devicePolicies/controlPanel/settings` in my breadcrumbs component. Now, I click on the `controlPanel` link in my breadcrumbs and I want to navigate to `controlPanel` and show that associated component. How can I do so?

Comment: @Tim what do you mean "How can I do so?" Are you asking how to use the `<Link>` component to create navigation links to routes? Or a deeper question behind how to render routes in react-router? In either case I suggest you go and read over the official react-router documentation and try some tutorials. It seems you need to spend some more time understanding it on your own before you come to Stack Overflow to ask more specific questions. We can't help you learn how to use react-router in the general sense -- that part is up to you. :) https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/philosophy